# How to disable discount on a category? - Nopcommerce

Tags: c#, .net, e-commerce, nopcommerce, discount

I created a 10% discount for order total. But I want to ignore it for a specific category. Any short ways to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some code. We have no idea what you're talking about. Also which part you have trouble with?

Comment: Well, you should have your order linked to category and than check it. Or you want to give discount if all items are in discount categories?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel this is not custom module, I'm creating using standard NopCommerce admin interface.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich, I want to apply discount to all products except one category.

Comment: Are all categories objects or is it an enum? If they are objects (every category has its own class), then why not add a Discount property, that contains the 10% for all but one. Perhaps even have a base class to not duplicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve your goal assigning the discount to all categories except the only one that shouldn't be affected.
So the properties should be

```
Discount Type: Assigned to categories
Assigned to categories: CategoryA CategoryB CategoryC
```